# Copy Feature Class to Feature Dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, coordinate-system, feature-class

On trying to copy a feature class to a feature dataset,  I get this error message 
(see the screen shot).

Any ideas how this is happening?

[error copying from FeatureClass to Feature Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sroYF.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The error message you are encountering is telling you that the coordinate systems do not match. For example may be you are trying to copy data that is WGS84 into a UTM defined FeatureDataset? All data copied into the FeatureDataset must match the FeatureDataset..

They have to match exactly on all spatial parameters, including extent. Use the `Feature Class to Feature Class` tool to overcome this.

Comment: Thanks Hornbydd, but unfortunately they share the same coordinate system, what should I consider else?

Comment: They have to match exactly on all spatial parameters, including extent.  Use the Feature Class to Feature Class tool to overcome this.

Comment: Thanks Richard, Feature Class to Feature Class was helpful tool and i overcome the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it seems that a feature class and a feature dataset have the same spatial references, but thats not always true! It's a nasty bug in ArcGis and it occurs quite often.

The solution is to update the spatial reference of the feature class with an arcpy-script. Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
fc = r"<<path to your feature class>>"
gdb = r"<<path to your gdb you want to export the feature class in>>"

sr = arcpy.Describe(r"<<path to your feature class>>").spatialReference

arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdb, "<<name of the feature dataset>>", sr)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc,gdb+"<<name of the feature dataset>>")
```

Change all values between `<<...>>`